# How to reappear a div with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an issue with my project.

I have this code to make disappear my div :

```
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

On my div I do this animation to make disappear my div after 6 seconds

```
.env{
  animation: hideAnimation 0s ease-in 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

My issue is : I want to create a button to reappear my div

The div disappear automatically after 6 seconds and the user can make reappear the div with a click on a button.

I don't know how to do that.

I think I will use JS or jQuery but I'm lost.
Can someone can help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: The problem with "opacity" is the following : The select button under my div will be unusable if my div "exist"

Comment: In that case you can use `z-index` to make the button appear over the div. It would help to have all relevant code, ie. the HTML and CSS, within the question so that we can create a full working example of the issue

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to fade in/out the div then `keyframes` is overkill. You can use `transition` with `opacity` instead.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  div.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
div { 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
} 

div.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle div</button>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need the button on `click` to get the `div` you want to reappear, and set its `visibility: visible;`

For example

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.env').style.visibility = 'visible';
})
```

For more resources

1. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
2. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
3. [HTMLElement style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)
4. [Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Comment: I think it's that but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MickaelCA7 So, please provide a full example of your code, so we can help you.